# Designing a textual user interface using ncurses.

Tags: ncurses

I'm planning to write a utility using ncurses. That is menus and panels on Unix.
Is there any way of designing my TUI to see how it looks and feels before I do the actual coding?

Are there any utilities for this, or some articles, links, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of ncurses but I don't know of any tool like this. You can try just doing pencil and paper or [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) mockups. Probably, the best thing to do is to write a slimmed down version of your UI without all the business logic and see how it feels from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question is no longer relevant, but still ..

I make a cell of the same length and width in LibreOffice Calc, and draw lines interface